# Question regarding Big O:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Let $f$ be a positive function such that $$f(n) = a f\left( \left\lfloor \frac nb\right\rfloor\right) + c$$ holds for every integer n ≥ 1, where a ≥ 1, b is an integer larger than one, and c ∈ R+ .

Prove that $f(n) = O(n^{\log_b a})$ if a > 1, and $f(n) = O(\ln n)$ if
a = 1

I don't understand where to begin, I tried using the formal definition of big O notation but still couldn't progress any further

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to have a look at some proofs of the [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) as your question seems extremely similar.

Comment: got it, thanks!